# tableChange() executing when the JTable is refreshed

Tags: java, swing, jtable

In my form I have a JTable with a TableModelListener.  The tableChanged method updates the logic on my JButtons.  This all works correctly.  When a user edits a value in a cell in the jtable - the tableChanged method executes and the buttons are refreshed accordingly.

The problem I am having and it is a show stopper.  The JTable displays objects and some attributes of the object.  The user selects the objects from the application.
If I there is a object selected and being displayed in the jtable. If that user changes a attribute value in the application and not edit it in the JTable.  The jtable is still refreshed and the changed value is displayed.  But a TableModelEvent is not taking place and my button logic is never refreshed.

I have looked at TableCellListeners - but that is still looking for a edit in the table.  So I don't think that will work here.

How can I tell that something has changed and the Table has been updated without a Event taking place in the jtable itself?

EDIT:  Placing some of the jtable code

This is in my base dialog class

```
selectTable = new JTable(SingletonSelectTable.getInstance());
selectTable.getModel().addTableModelListener(this); 
selectTable.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
     public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row, int column) {
        Component comp = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
        Font font = comp.getFont();
        if (SingletonSelectTable.getInstance().isCellBold(row, column) == true){
           comp.setFont(font.deriveFont(Font.BOLD));
        }
     return comp;
     }
  });

selectTable.setAutoResizeMode(JTable.AUTO_RESIZE_ALL_COLUMNS);
selectTable.setCellSelectionEnabled(false);
selectTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
selectTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(false);
JScrollPane ScrollPane = new JScrollPane(selectTable);
```

the tableChanged method

```
public void tableChanged(TableModelEvent e) {
  setRemoveButtonVisibility();
  setRemoveAllButtonVisibility();
  setCommentButtonVisibility();
  setOKButtonEnabledStatus();
```

}

my singleton class

```
public class SingletonSelectTable extends AbstractTableModel {
```

I hope this helps

Comment: How does the JTable cell change without the TableModel changing?

Comment: no idea..., for better help sooner post an SSCCE

Comment: The getValueAt() method picks up the change and then updates the jtable

Comment: Please edit your question to include an [sscce](http://sscce.org/) that exhibits the problem you describe.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> How can I tell that something has changed and the Table has been updated without a Event taking place in the jtable itself?

There is never an event in the `JTable`. It is the underlying `TableModel` that changes, and it is the `TableModel` that fires an event.
The `JTable` registers a listener to the `TableModel` so it knows when it should update the displayed table content.

So if you are saying that the `JTable` gets updated (automatically, so without you scrolling/selecting/hovering/...) means that the `TableModel` does fire an event, meaning you can also listen for it.

In the scenario an element of your `TableModel` is changed in your application, something should fire the `TableModelEvent` from the `TableModel`. Typically this is done by either letting the `TableModel` listen for changes in the objects it contains, or letting the code that changes the object also notify the `TableModel` that the underlying data has been changed. Either way, the `TableModel` needs to fire an event, so there is no reason why your listener would not receive it, unless it is simply not fired (meaning an incorrect `TableModel`).

My best guess, based on your comments, is that you have an incorrect implementation of your `TableModel` and that your `TableModel` simply does not fire an event, and that the `JTable` gets updated 'by accident' (in my experience is a `JTable` rather robust for missing events, certainly when no rows are added/removed ... definetely compared to a `JTree`)

> The getValueAt() method picks up the change and then updates the jtable

This really sounds incorrect. The `getValueAt()` method is normally called by the `JTable` after it receives an event. Thanks to the event, the `JTable` knows it must be updated so it queries the model for the new data. So the `getValueAt` method does not pick up the change, but gets called as a result of the change.

I would strongly suggest to take a look at the [Swing table tutorial](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html), and certainly the sections about [Creating a table model](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#data), [Listening for data changes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#modelchange) and [Firing data change events](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/components/table.html#fire)

Comment: You are correct the jtable does not just refresh the change automatic.  The change can appear when a cell is clicked or the dialog is resized.  But those actions does not cause the a tableChanged event.  If I add a row or remove a row, edit a cell.  Those all cause the tableChanged event to run.

Comment: That means you do not fire the appropriate event. It is up to the `TableModel` to take care of this, but it won't happen automagically. You will have to write some code for it